# Why "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)" error is not being nice to me?

Tags: c

I was writing some (**C**) code and encountered this error. I know segmentation fault is due to pointer going wild, but my code was working properly before the addition of some non-pointer statements (most of them are declaration statements) to it. My code is large enough and quite a mess(right now). Then to solve my problem I wrote another test code(to copy char array) to check what wrong is going on.

Here it is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 8
#define MAX2 12

char* copy(char[]);
void copy2(char*,char*);

int main()
{
    char line[MAX]="Copy Me!";
    //char line2[MAX2]="Copy Me Too!";              //stmt 1
    char* b;
    b=copy(line);
    printf("copy(): %s",b);

    /*copy2(line2,b);                               //stmt
    printf("\ncopy2(): %s",b);                      //  2
    */
    return 0;
}

char* copy(char orig[])
{
    int i;
    char* copy;
    //copy=(char*) malloc(sizeof(orig));            //stmt 3
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
    copy[i]=orig[i];
    return copy;
}

void copy2(char *orig, char *copy)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<MAX2;i++)
    {
        copy[i] = orig[i];
    }
}
```

This code works fine even without stmt 3 (Mark the comments) for malloc, but debugger still points to `char* copy;` so why does it works correctly?
And it gives SIGSEGV in following cases:

1. When `Max` is greater than 8, and 'why' is the question.
2. Or if you just include the stmt 1 back in code, its simple declaration, what it has to do with pointers or is it sharing something with **line[]**?

If I place stmt 1 and stmt 3 back in code everything works.

Also tell me, how to allocate `copy` to contain just the number of charachters `orig` contains, by this I mean if `orig[10]="Hi";` is used for getting size for `malloc` then we'll get 10 bytes even if `orig[10]="Hi";` contains 2 char.

And share some codes like this (containing errors which may not appear at first but with some updates it all stops working).
And some place(for beginner) to find small open source project where I can read other people's codes and possibly add few of mine, I'm trying to learn C, C++ and Java.

If something I've not mentioned here or is not clear(my English), let me know of it. And sorry I've asked too many questions here at one place.

Comment: You didn't leave room for the null terminator in your string...

Comment: Also, `copy` (in the identically named function) is uninitialized.

Comment: Remember, in plain C very little is checked at runtime. If you do improper things like accessing data through a freed pointer, anything could happen. You might get a segmentation fault, you might corrupt other data, or you **might** get a program that seems like it's working just fine. That doesn't mean that it's correct. :)

Comment: And also, `Segmentation Violation` is being very nice with you. This, on realtime systems, would probably cause the system to die!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
copy=(char*) malloc(sizeof(orig));
```

First, this statement is necessary. If you remove it, `copy` has some garbage value. It *might* point to allocated memory, and you *might* not get an error immediately, but your code will be broken and there's no telling what will happen.

Second, `sizeof(orig)` is not the size of the array you passed in. It's the size of a `char *`, since array arguments are automatically converted to pointers. You can't actually pass a whole array by value in C. You need to determine the size of the allocation you need some other way, either by passing it as an argument, by hardcoding it (as MAX, probably), or by looking for the string's null terminator. (On that note, you didn't leave room for the null terminator when you first created the string to copy.)

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't `char line[MAX]="Hello";` get terminated by `\0`? If not, then how can it be printed using `printf("%s",line)? Does it get printed till the size of line, But how does it knows the size if it only points to the start and there is no `\0`?

Comment: @learning: `"Hello"` fits in the space you provided. `"Copy Me!"` doesn't.

Comment: Even in the case of Copy me!, I intentionally add '!'to make it 8 character long (As well as copy me too! is 12(MAX2) character long) just to know if it ends with '\0' or not. How does that work without '\0' with printf.

Comment: @learning: It doesn't!  You have undefined behavior. You might get something that seems to work, or you might crash, or you might execute some attacker's cleverly-injected shellcode and hand control of the computer to bad guys.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help and warning my processor was already making freaky buzzing sound with that segmentation fault. It is safe to use pointers for learning, right? What I know is that OS maintains HW and SW or files etc, so using pointers may affect the data used by that program only like opened files and in some cases if programmer is using some system commands and all.

Answer (score 2):

> This code works fine even without stmt 3 (Mark the comments) for malloc, but debugger still points to char* copy; so why does it works correctly?

Just because the program runs without crashing does not mean that the program is correct.  Many error cases in C will run without error but are in fact very wrong.  The use of `copy` in the below code is one such example

```
char* copy;
copy=(char*) malloc(sizeof(orig));      
for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
    copy[i]=orig[i];
```

In order for this code to be correct `copy` must point to at least `MAX` bytes of memory.  Without the `malloc` statement it points to garbage and with `malloc` it points to the size of pointer (which on x86 would be 4 not 8).  Instead do the following

```
copy = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX);
```

Comment: Thanks. Please explain one more thing why `sizeof(orig)` worked in my case? Its is working for `MAX 50` also and may be work with more.

Comment: @learning just because it ran it didn't crash didn't mean it worked.  It can still be very wrong but you can just get lucky that it runs correctly.  Such is the nature of C

Comment: Thanks, I just asked because I want to clear all this stuff, there must be some reason. Thank you for answering.